# Apex Visualforce page styling remove underline and text align

Tags: apex, visualforce, stylesheets, sfdc-styleguide

This image shows the output of the Visualforce page:

1. How to text-align Opp Created Date to the right the page?
2. How to remove all the underlines?
   [image]

here is the code:

```
 <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:repeat value="{!opps}" var="o">                        
         <apex:outputText style="text-decoration:none;" value="Opp Name: {!o.Name}"/> <hr/>                        
         <apex:outputText value="Opp Close Date: {!o.CloseDate}"/>
         <apex:outputText style="color:white;" value="----------"/> 
         <apex:outputText value="Opp Created Date: {!o.CreatedDate}"/>  <hr/> 
     </apex:repeat>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the lines, don't use `<hr />`. You probably want a table:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="o">                        
        <apex:column style="text-decoration:none;" headerValue="Opportunity Name" value="{!o.Name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Close Date" value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Created Date" value="{!o.CreatedDate}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```